# How can I render all inline formulas in $..$ with KaTeX?

Tags: javascript, katex

So I want to have KaTeX inline formulas like with MathJax.
But so far I've found only `render()` function which "draws" a string to an element.
And I need to modify a part of a text node in DOM.
I really couldn't find how to do this with KaTeX. Does it have such functionality?
MathJax could do this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you can render all `$`-delimited formulas inline using KaTeX's [auto-render extension](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/blob/master/contrib/auto-render/README.md). Per the documentation on that page, `$` is not one of the default delimiters so you'll need to set it when you call `renderMathInElement()` and set `display` to `false`, which renders inline. Below is one example and another from KaTeX can be found [here](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/blob/master/contrib/auto-render/index.html).

Note that `\\` in the JavaScript corresponds to `\` in the HTML.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.7.1/katex.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.7.1/katex.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.7.1/contrib/auto-render.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>The formula $a^2+b^2=c^2$ will be rendered inline, but $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$ will be rendered as a block element.</div>
    <br>
    <div>The formula \(a^2+b^2=c^2\) will be rendered inline, but \[a^2+b^2=c^2\] will be rendered as a block element.</div>
    <script>
      renderMathInElement(
          document.body,
          {
              delimiters: [
                  {left: "$$", right: "$$", display: true},
                  {left: "\\[", right: "\\]", display: true},
                  {left: "$", right: "$", display: false},
                  {left: "\\(", right: "\\)", display: false}
              ]
          }
      );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi...Thats an amazing answer.. Is it possible to define equation environments also like mathjax ?

Answer (score 5):

As of early 2020, it seems that KaTeX 0.11.1 supports inline maths without using the "hack" in the answer by Vincent. The single dollar delimiters `$ ... $` do not work but the escaped brackets `\( ... \)` instead do, as in the following minimal code and snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Katex 0.11.1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-zB1R0rpPzHqg7Kpt0Aljp8JPLqbXI3bhnPWROx27a9N0Ll6ZP/+DiW/UqRcLbRjq" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-y23I5Q6l+B6vatafAwxRu/0oK/79VlbSz7Q9aiSZUvyWYIYsd+qj+o24G5ZU2zJz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-kWPLUVMOks5AQFrykwIup5lo0m3iMkkHrD0uJ4H5cjeGihAutqP0yW0J6dpFiVkI" crossorigin="anonymous" onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"></script>
</head>

<body>
Lorem ipsum 
$e^{i\pi}+1=0$ <!-- does not work -->
dolor sit amet, 
\(e^{i\pi}+1=0\) <!-- this works -->
consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-zB1R0rpPzHqg7Kpt0Aljp8JPLqbXI3bhnPWROx27a9N0Ll6ZP/+DiW/UqRcLbRjq" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-y23I5Q6l+B6vatafAwxRu/0oK/79VlbSz7Q9aiSZUvyWYIYsd+qj+o24G5ZU2zJz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-kWPLUVMOks5AQFrykwIup5lo0m3iMkkHrD0uJ4H5cjeGihAutqP0yW0J6dpFiVkI" crossorigin="anonymous" onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"></script>
Lorem ipsum 
$e^{i\pi}+1=0$ <!-- does not work -->
dolor sit amet, 
\(e^{i\pi}+1=0\) <!-- this works -->
consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

After some tests, I couldn't make dollar delimiters `$ ... $` work but the brackets `\( ... \)` here working by default are an update respect to version 0.7.1 of KaTeX (anyway still available).

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/issues/712#issuecomment-304531595) is the related discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get the answer by @Vincent to work. I had to wrap the `renderMathInElement` in a `document.addEventListener`. Like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.6/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-ZPe7yZ91iWxYumsBEOn7ieg8q/o+qh/hQpSaPow8T6BwALcXSCS6C6fSRPIAnTQs" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- The loading of KaTeX is deferred to speed up page rendering -->
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.6/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-ljao5I1l+8KYFXG7LNEA7DyaFvuvSCmedUf6Y6JI7LJqiu8q5dEivP2nDdFH31V4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- To automatically render math in text elements, include the auto-render extension: -->
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.6/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-+XBljXPPiv+OzfbB3cVmLHf4hdUFHlWNZN5spNQ7rmHTXpd7WvJum6fIACpNNfIR" crossorigin="anonymous"
        onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"></script>
<script>
    // https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/blob/main/docs/autorender.md
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        renderMathInElement(document.body, {
            // customised options
            // • auto-render specific keys, e.g.:
                delimiters: [
                {left: '$$', right: '$$', display: true},
                {left: '$', right: '$', display: false},
                {left: '\(', right: '\)', display: false},
                {left: '\[', right: '\]', display: true},
                {left: "\begin{equation}", right: "\end{equation}", display: true},
                {left: "\begin{align}", right: "\end{align}", display: true},
            ],
            // • rendering keys, e.g.:
            throwOnError : false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

render can take an extra third argument (default is false) to select
inline displaymode:

```
katex.render("c = \\pm\\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}", element, { displayMode: true });
```

Is this what you are looking for?