# Render TeX with KaTeX or MathJax

Tags: javascript, node.js, mathjax, tex, katex

I have a html document

```
<div>
  <p>One paragraph</p>
  <p>Another paragraph</p>
</div>
```

and in some of the paragraphs, I have

```
<p>Some text and a formula $a = b + c$.</p>
```

and I want the text withing the $-signs to be rendered as TeX math using [KaTeX](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX).

The problem is that if I want to use it in the browser, I have to use

```
katex.render("c = \\pm\\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}", element);
```

so I need to assign an element.

So should I really write my html document like this or are there any other options:

```
<div>
  <p>One paragraph</p>
  <p>Another paragraph</p>
  <p>Some text and a formula <span id="firstFormula"></span>.</p>
  <p>More text and another formula <span id="secondFormula"></span>.</p>
</div>
<script>
  const firstFormula = document.getElementById('firstFormula');
  katex.render("c = \\pm\\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}", firstFormula);

  const secondFormula = document.getElementById('secondFormula');
  katex.render("c = \\pm\\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}", secondFormula);
</script>
```

and repeat the same pattern for each formula?

It seems a bit weird that I cannot just write the text and replace all the text formulas with tex rendered output.

How does, for instance, Khan Academy do it on [this page](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/one-dimensional-motion/kinematic-formulas/a/what-are-the-kinematic-formulas) where they combine text and formulas? Do they render everything on the server and send it to the client?

Is it better to use MathJax in this situation? I am just more keen on KaTeX since it is much faster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I render all inline formulas in $..$ with KaTeX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375252/how-can-i-render-all-inline-formulas-in-with-katex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, MathJax doesn't use `$` as delimiters. So you'll have to configure them manually.

The following example using MathJax is from its [documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax TeX Test Page</title>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">
</script>
</head>
<body>
When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to use KaTeX, you'll need to include the script to auto render and make it use `$` as delimiters. See https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/blob/master/contrib/auto-render/README.md for instructions. [Here](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/blob/master/contrib/auto-render/index.html) is an example.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.