# Render math with KaTeX in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, mathjax, katex

I am using `KaTeX` to render math in the browser.

Right now I am using something like

```
document.getElementById('el').innerHTML = function () {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  katex.render('2+\frac{1}{x}', span);
  return span.innerHTML;
});
```

but it seems really stupid that I have to apply it to an element, and then take the html from this element and insert in my string.

I have looked through the KaTeX documentation, but I cannot find anything to help me just rendering some text directly in the browser with something like `katex.render('2+3+4')`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39930756/render-tex-with-katex-or-mathjax

Comment: Why not simply `katex.render('2+\\frac{1}{x}', document.getElementById('el'));`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you're still looking for an answer but maybe this will be helpful.

First, I link to katex.min.js and katex.min.css from a cdn.

I wrap everything I want rendered in katex inside span tags and give them the class 'math'

For example:

```
<span class='math'>2+\frac{1}{x}</span>
```

Then inside a pair of script tags I include something like this:

```
var math = document.getElementsByClassName('math');
for (var i = 0; i < math.length; i++) {
  katex.render(math[i].textContent, math[i]);
}
```

So as long as I write my math text inside an element with the class math, it gets rendered by katex.

EDIT: We should use **textContent** instead of innerHTML. I've run into issues using innerHTML. See [using katex, '&' alignment symbol displays as 'amp;'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49719914/using-katex-alignment-symbol-displays-as-amp/53754842#53754842)

Answer (score 3):

Use KaTeX's [auto-render extension](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/blob/master/contrib/auto-render/README.md), which will let you add your KaTeX directly to the HTML with a delimiter like `$$` and then render it all at once:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.7.1/katex.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.7.1/katex.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.7.1/contrib/auto-render.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="el"><span>$$2+\frac{1}{x}$$</span></div>
    <script>
        renderMathInElement(document.body);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can I use this extension with Node? npm install katex doesnt include this extension